# how do i rename fei62x64.sys in order to enable TPM

Tags: driver, rename, tpm

Trying to turn on TPM on a computer with the TPM chip on windows 10 pro, version 10.0.19043, build 19043
Get a message to resolve any driver incompatibilities and scan again
I reviewed  incompatible driver list
fei62x64.sys is the only one listed
It appears to be an intel network driver with creation date 10/1/2009

I have searched through stack for similar problems and they have not helped

I tried a program called dependency walker to see if it is in use and could not determine if it was
I added my userid and administrator explicitly with full control to the file

Looked at each of the entries for Intel under device manager driver details and the driver, fei62x64 is not mentioned
Decided to try to rename file
First did backup, fresh system image, and restore point
Unable to rename file
Added my personal user id and administrator as owners with full control
Still unable to rename file.  The error I get is

ren : Access to the path is denied.
At line:1 char:1

- ren fei62x64.sys fei62x64.old
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\windows\syst...c1\fei62x64.sys:String) [Rename-Item], Unauthorized
  AccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
  ```

Checked with computer maker, Puget Systems, and they sent a list of updated drivers which had no impact on this issue since fei62x64 remains.
Any thoughts on how to either rename this file or another way to allow me to enable to turn on core isolation with fei62x64 listed as incompatible driver

Answer (score 1):

Okay I think my best solution is to use pnputil, a microsoft utility which allows you to delete a driver.  Obviously be good to do a backup before using something like this. pnputil will allow you to delete individual drivers